# How to use UserCamera->ViewController()?

Tags: control, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am running gazebo2.2.

I want to control UserCam ,and looked up in API doc(http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1UserCamera.html#a7148635d156d63c3e163bf1c28bb547e)

I found three function as following:

EnableViewController(TRUE);
SetFocalPoint(math::Vector3(0,0,0.1));
SetViewController("orbit",math::Vector3(0,1,0.5));

So , I imaged that my userCam would orbit the point(0,0,0.1)

but, It turned  out nothing happened!

Did I miss some steps?

Thank you~!

if it is possible, can you check my code?

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/emWnSf00

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8179/how-to-use-usercamera-%3Eviewcontroller()?/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

"orbit" is the type of interaction used with the 3d canvas. Meaning when you click the mouse and you move it it orbits the point where you clicked. Or something like that .. :)

In order to move the camera you will have to get the camera pointer and apply new positions for it.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1